# Type of Properties method in Stanford Core NLP

Tags: c#, winforms, stanford-nlp

I am building a front end to parse some text files using Stanford Core NLP in C#. I open a file selection dialog and select some text files. Then the following method works from there on.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using java.util;
using java.io;
using edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline;

namespace Parser_SVO
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<string> textFiles = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textFiles.AddRange(openFileDialog1.FileNames);
            }
            parseText();
        }
        public static void parseText()
        {
            label2.Text = "Stanford Parser....";
            // Path to the folder with models extracted from `stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar`
            string jarRoot = "";
            string prettyPrint = "";
            if (textFiles.Count != 0)
            {
                jarRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(textFiles[0]) + @"\Models\";
                prettyPrint = Path.GetDirectoryName(textFiles[0]);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(prettyPrint + @"\PrettyPrint\");
                prettyPrint = prettyPrint + @"\PrettyPrint\";
            }
            // Annotation pipeline configuration
            var props = Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
            props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");

            // We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
            var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);
            var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);
            foreach (string file in textFiles)
            {
                label3.Text = file;
                // Text for processing
                var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
                // Annotation
                var annotation = new Annotation(text);
                pipeline.annotate(annotation);
                // Result - Pretty Print
                string output = prettyPrint + Path.GetFileName(file);
                using (var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
                {
                    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, new PrintWriter(stream));
                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(output, stream.toString()+Environment.NewLine);
                    stream.close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have modified the example from official StanfordCoreNLP .Net port [here](https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html). 
Since I am using Windows Forms instead of Console application, this line of code is creating problem: `var props = Properties();`. I am not sure how to find the namespace of this method to provide a complete namespace.class.method path to disambiguate.
Another minor problem is that I want to update label text as in `label2.Text = "Stanford Parser....";` but visual studio says that "An object reference is required" while I am in the same class (Forms1.cs). Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `java.util.Properties` is the Type. Did you mean `var props = new Properties();` ?

Comment: Yes. Figured it out afterwards. Now I am struggling with changing text of a label from a static method. And there does not seem to be a single staring answer available.

Comment: You could take a `Label` as a parameter but that is kind of hacky: `public static void ParseText(Label lbl)`, then do `lbl.Text = "...";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Properties() class is java.util.Properties.
Simply remove `static` from the method name to access windows forms objects like text box or label.